# Unwanted rendering on same page with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router-v4

I'm currently working with React-router-dom (React router 4) and I want a detail page for customers. I can get all the data succesfully, but the data shows on the same page as the list/overview. The image will clarify things.I would like to have two separate views.

[image: unwanted rendering on same page]

This is the structure of the router:

```
const unauthenticatedPages = [
  '/',
  '/login'
];
const authenticatedPages = [
  '/admin'
];

// public pages
const publicPage = () => {
  if(Meteor.userId()) {
    history.push('/');
  }
};

// private pages
const privatePage = () => {
  if(Meteor.userId()) {
    history.push('/');
  }
};

// check authentication for pages
export const onAuthenticationChange = (authenticated) => {
  console.log('is authenticated...', authenticated);

  const path = this.location.pathname;
  const isUnauthenticatedPage = unauthenticatedPages.includes(path);
  const isAuthenticatedPage = authenticatedPages.includes(path);

  if( authenticated && isUnauthenticatedPage ) {
    console.log('Can view the page routed to the path dashboard');
  } else if (!authenticated && isAuthenticatedPage) {
    console.log('No rights to view the page... routed to the path 
    login page');
  }
}

// render app inside custom templates
const RouteWithLayout = ({layout, component, ...rest}) => {
  return (
   <Route {...rest} render={ (props) => React.createElement( layout, props, React.createElement(component, props)) } />
  );
};

export const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <RouteWithLayout exact path="/" layout={AuthenticationLayout} onEnter={publicPage} component={AuthLogin} />
        <RouteWithLayout path="/login" layout={AuthenticationLayout} onEnter={publicPage} component={AuthLogin} />

        <AdminLayout>
            <Route path="/admin" component={AdminDashboard} />
            <Route path="/klanten/:customerID" component= . {CustomerDetails} />
            <Route path="/klanten" component={CustomerOverview} />

            <Route path="/nieuwe-klant" component={CustomerCreate} />
        </AdminLayout>

        <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

Extra information:
I have some more issues with this router. I have used alanning:roles because the users have to be router based on the role they have. the image show the admin area, but the users will be using a simular layout with less options. How can I achieve this?

If I use a separate route like /new-customer/ I see a new page with only a form, but I would like to use /customer/new/ as the route. If I change the route to /customer/new/ my page won't be rendered.

Code of the /new-customer/ page:

```
class CustomerCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        message: ''
    };
  }
  onFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const relationNumber                = this.refs.relationNumber.value;
    const companyName                   = this.refs.companyName.value;
    const locationStreet                = this.refs.locationStreet.value;
    const locationPostal                = this.refs.locationPostal.value;
    const locationCity                  = this.refs.locationCity.value;
    const contactPersonName         = this.refs.contactPersonName.value;
    const contactPersonEmail        = this.refs.contactPersonEmail.value;
    const contactPersonPhone        = this.refs.contactPersonPhone.value;
    const password                          = this.refs.password.value;
    const confirmPassword           = this.refs.confirmPassword.value;

    const checkEmail = (email) => {
    const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
        const validated = regex.test(email);
        return validated;
    };

    const checkPassword = ( pwd, pwd2 ) => {
        if( pwd != '' || pwd2 != '' ){
            if ( pwd.length >= 5 ) { 
                if ( pwd === pwd2 ) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    const validatedEmail = checkEmail( contactPersonEmail );
    const validatedPassword = checkPassword( password, confirmPassword 
 ); 

    if(!validatedEmail) {
        this.setState({message: 'Het e-mailadres is niet correct.'});
    }
    if(!validatedPassword ) {
        this.setState({message: 'De wachtwoorden komen niet overeen!'});
    }

    if( validatedEmail && validatedPassword ) {
        try {
            const createdAccount = Accounts.createUser({
                email                       : contactPersonEmail,
                password                : password,
                relationNumber  : relationNumber,
                companyName         : companyName ,
                locationStreet  : locationStreet,
                locationPostal  : locationPostal,
                locationCity        : locationCity,
                contactName         : contactPersonName,
                contactPhone        : contactPersonPhone,
                isArchived          : 0,
                setRoles                : ['customer']
            });

            this.setState({message: 'De klant is succesvol toegevoegd!'});

            // send flashmessage of succesfull state

            return createdAccount;
        } catch( err ) {
            return err.reason;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
         form sitting here ...
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default CustomerCreate;
```

Comment: try adding exact={true} to :             <Route path="/klanten/:customerID" component= . {CustomerDetails} exact={true}  /> as I think it is now loading both this route and the next one which is /klanten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Switch component only renders a single of it's **immediate** children. Because your `/klanten` and `/klanten/:customerID` routes are not direct children of the  component they will both render whenever the route matches `/klanten*`

You can use the `exact` property on the `/klanten` route so that it will not match the `/klanten/:customerID` route.

```
<Route path="/klanten/:customerID" component= . {CustomerDetails} />
<Route path="/klanten" exact component={CustomerOverview} />
```

Comment: This did the trick. Although I made a small type with the '.'. I did try to add exact before, but on the route with the param. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's because both routes match `klanten`. Try renaming the client details path to `kunde`. Or, as others have suggested, add the `exact` property to the klanten overview path.

To answer question 2, put `customer/new` before `customer/:id` in your switch. And make sure that a customer can never have an id of 'new'.

Answer (score 0):

Right now React-Router is first rendering :

```
    <Route path="/klanten/:customerID" component= . {CustomerDetails} />
```

and then :

```
    <Route path="/klanten" component={CustomerOverview} />
```

when you go to any path which include /klanten.

Either rename one of the two routes or add exact={true} as follow :

```
    <Route path="/klanten/:customerID" component= . {CustomerDetails} exact={true} />
```